# Adding prefix to category and product URL

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-community

This is for Magento 1.
How to programmatically add prefix to **product url and category url**

so that category url would have `http://domain.com/cp/category-name.html`
and product url would have `http://domain.com/ip/product-name.html`

I tried

```
<global>
    <models>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_url>Mymod_Catalog_Model_Product_Url</product_url>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </models>
</global>
```

and override getUrl() method to add prefix to request_path.
is it the best to achieve it by this way?

I also tried to create observer and hook into event '`controller_front_init_routers`' but I totally got lost in there.

And I also need to know how to handle the new URL without using config.xml since the prefixes will be dynamic, taken from database config.
So that http://domain.com/cp/category-name.html would map to http://domain.com/category-name.html
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Prefix to Product URL’s in Magento

This is a very simple modification that requires you duplicate and modify one file. Do not modify URL.php directly, when you update your changes will be overwritten.

**Copy:**

```
/app/code/core/mage/catalog/model/url.php
```

**To:**

```
/app/code/local/mage/catalog/model/url.php
```

Replace :

```
if ($category->getLevel() > 1) {
           // To ensure, that category has path either from attribute or generated now
           $this->_addCategoryUrlPath($category);
           $categoryUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrlPath($category->getUrlPath(),
               false, $storeId);
           $requestPath = $categoryUrl . '/' . $urlKey;
       } else {
           $requestPath = $urlKey;
       }
```

**To:**

```
if ($category->getLevel() > 1) {
            // To ensure, that category has path either from attribute or generated now
            $this->_addCategoryUrlPath($category);
            $categoryUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrlPath($category->getUrlPath(),
                false, $storeId);
            $requestPath = 'product-p/' .$categoryUrl . '/' . $urlKey;
        } else {
            $requestPath = 'product-p/' .$urlKey;
        }
}
```

Above, find “product-p” and change it to your desired prefix for products.

Comment: We already have lot of products. we want to programmatically add prefix to product url without regenerate the old product key.

Comment: @Doni pls check edited answer.

Comment: I've seen this in another thread. I don't want to copy core file to local. We can achieve the same result using rewrite. question is,  is it the best way?

Comment: btw, how to handle the new url then?

Comment: yes, you can rewrite and replace this code it will be done.